# How to make the text layer shrink only after no more than 5% is left to the window border?

Tags: html, css, resize

I'm stuck with this, could you help me with div resize problem?
How can I make the text layer shrink only after no more than 5% is left to the window borders?

Below the code-snippet:

```css
    * {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
     height: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
     position: relative;
     min-height: 100%;
    }
    .content {
     padding-bottom: 90px;
     text-align:center;
     padding-top:10%;
    }
    .footer {
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 40px;
     
    }

    .content div { 
    width:36%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:justify;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
     <div class="content">
     <div>
    
    Text text Text textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText textText text</div>
     
     </div>
     <div class="footer">text text</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build in a condition, you have to use mediaqueries. For example

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.example {
max-width: 30px;
 }
}
```

Maybe you can get more in touch width conditions and mediaqueries in generally by the following link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
It represents an introduction.